# Accessing Flask REST Api with Curl doesn't work

Tags: python, curl, flask-restful

I have built a very simple flask api which asks a neural network what kind of language has been given via POST.

**Request**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{"""text""":"""This should be recognized as an english text."""}""" http://<IP>:5000/api/v1.0/findlanguage
```

Api calls via GET are working within the browser, and they return all desired json objects. Flask is also responding on the serverside that there has been a GET request which he returned with HTTP Code 200.

But the POST request above doesn't provoke any output from Flask. It enters some kind of console I guess because I all see is this:

```
>_
```

That's it. What might this be? Am I missing something?

Expected output should be a json object like:

```
{
   'task': 'findlanguage',
   'result': 'english',
   'api': 'v1.0',
   'call': 'http://<ip>:5000/api/v1.0/findlanguage'
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's all the double-quotes? Try to change your request body to: `'{"text":"This should be recognized as an english text."}'`

Comment: Did you have any output of flask(which/what incoming) ? Type of post got more pattern which used on server side ?

Comment: I implemented it according to this tutorial https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask where it says that you need these tripple-double-quotes within a linux environment. If I try it without the double-quotes flask returns HTTP Error 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @dsgdfg: unfortunately no. nothing on the serverside.

Comment: Are you using bash? In bash, triple quotes doesn't do what you're intending. You need to do either: `'"'` or `"\""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request isn’t getting sent at all; the shell’s waiting for further input before running `curl` at all.

> But the POST request above doesn't provoke any output from Flask. It enters some kind of console I guess because I all see is this:
>
> ```
> >_
> ```

That’s what you’ll see if the command has unbalanced quote characters. For example, try:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json""
```

If you type another `"` at that prompt and hit the `return` key, the command will execute.

That’s just an example though. The problem in the command example in the question isn’t due to the quotes around that `Content-Type` string but instead due to the argument to the `-d` option.

Are you really using `"""` three-doublequotes-in-a-row there. If so, why?

Regardless, you got a single doublequote character before the open `{` brace character there, and then three doublequote characters after the closing `}` brace, which sorta clearly seems not right.

Why don’t you just put the `-d` argument in single quotes:

```
-d '{"text":"This should be recognized as an english text."}'
```

Comment: Ok I just learned something new. Thanks :-) It worked finally. There has been an error on the server side. I always got HTTP 500 back with single quotes. Python told me something about errors within the code. Fixed it, it works ... Sometimes you just do not see it. Thank you all!